# Jquery animations do not run simultaneously

Tags: jquery, animation

Ive been trying to figure out how to get all three animations in the script below to animate simultaneously when an element is clicked. Currently one element runs and then the other after it has completed. Not sure what the issue is as I have tried many suggested solutions to similar posts and had no luck.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var $dropDownWrapper = $( '#dropdown-wrapper' );


    $("#clickme").click(function() {

        var wrapperHeight = $dropDownWrapper.css("height");


        if( wrapperHeight == '3px') {

          $('#clickme').animate({"margin-top": "200px"}, 400, 'swing');

            $('#arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 3px');

          $dropDownWrapper.animate({"height": "200px"}, 400);





        }

        else {

          $('#clickme').animate({"margin-top": "3px"}, 400, 'swing');

          $dropDownWrapper.animate( {"height": "3px"}, 400, 'swing');

          $('#arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -10px');


        }
    });
 });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
       if( wrapperHeight == '3px') {

          $('#clickme').animate({
               "margin-top": "200px"
          },{ duration: 400, queue: false, easing: "swing"});

          $dropDownWrapper.animate({
              "height": "200px"
          },{ duration: 400, queue: false, easing: "swing"  });

          $('#arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 3px');

        } else {

          $('#clickme').animate({
              "margin-top": "3px"
          }, { duration: 400, queue: false, easing: "swing"  });

          $dropDownWrapper.animate({
             "height": "3px"
          }, { duration: 400, queue: false, easing: "swing" });

          $('#arrow').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -10px');

        }
```

***[Check this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pFSdM/1/)***

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I tried the code above and it still animates the items separately.

Comment: yes, it does seem to work perfectly in your demo. For some reason it still doesnt work when I use it on my site. Could it be the version of jquery im using?

Comment: another strange thing i noticed is that the arrow position executes at the same time as the div height expansion. Weird.